# No puedo introducir claves foráneas como nulas en SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Estoy implementando una base de datos en mi aplicación Android y me esta dando más problemas de los que pensaba en un principio.

Mi BD organiza el trabajo diario de los estudiantes, apuntando los trabajos que tienen que entregar, las asignaturas, los profesores, los estudios, los eventos (excursiones), horarios, etc.

Resulta que las tablas `Asignatura`, `Evento` y `Deber` están enlazadas con la tabla `Horario` con relaciones ***uno a muchos***, quedando en la tabla `Horario` las claves foráneas hacia sus respectivas tablas. Justo como aparece en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas claves foráneas deber ser **nulas** porque *un horario solo puede pertenecer a un solo `Evento` o a una sola `Asignatura` o a un solo `Deber`*, pero el SQLite de Android no deja introducir claves foráneas con un dato que no exista en la tabla relacionada o un dato nulo (es imposible porque es de tipo `int`).

Explico un ejemplo:

- Los datos `Asignatura_id`, `Evento_id` y `Deber_id` son de tipo `int`por lo que no puedo insertar un valor `null` en el campo que tenga un enlace (FK).
- Si inserto el dato `Horario(Fecha, Hora_Inicio, Hora_Fin, Asignatura_id, Evento_id, Deber_id)` siguiente, pongo `Evento_id` y `Deber_id` con valores `-1` para decir que no están relacionados con nada.

  ```
  horario.add(new Horario("2016-03-15", "16:00:00", "19:00:00", 2, -1, -1));
  ```
- El resultado es el siguiente error en el `logcat`:

  ```
  Error inserting Deber_id=-1 Evento_id=-1 Hora_Inicio=16:00:00 Asignatura_id=2 Fecha=2016-03-15 Hora_Fin=19:00:00                                                      
  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787)
  ```
- Este error viene dado porque el valor `-1` no existe en las tablas `Evento` y `Deber`.

Dicho todo esto, mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto? ¿Puedo poner algún valor que haga la misma función que el nulo?

He pensado en varias soluciones:

- Crear un registro **no valido** en cada una de las tres tablas y cuando quiera meter un valor nulo en la tabla `Horario`, referenciar a este. Por ejemplo: crear un primer registro con todos los datos posibles a null, así el primer registro de las tres tablas (con `_id` = 1) seria como un comodín.
- Crear una **jerarquía** que salga desde `Horario`, es decir, crear las siguientes tablas:

  - **Horario:** _id, Fecha, Hora_Inicio y Hora_Fin (no nulos).
  - **HorarioEvento:** _id, Evento_id (no nulos, FK a Evento._id).
  - **HorarioAsignatura:** _id, Asignatura_id (no nulos, FK a Asignatura._id).
  - **HorarioDeber:** _id, Deber_id (no nulo, FK a Deber._id).

Me gustaría saber que opináis al respecto o si encontráis otra solución más sencilla de implementar.

Mi principal problema es el tiempo, ya que necesito hacer funcionar la BD para la semana que viene, por eso necesito algo rápido de configurar y que funcione.

Estoy abierta a cualquier solución y a cualquier ayuda. Puedo recompensarla.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final la solución era crear una jerarquía. Me he contestado yo sola en la misma pregunta. Aún así, gracias.